# ERROR: Error installing rails: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos

I was getting some json errors on my rails app (it was on a pretty old version) at one point, some mysql errors at others, so I reinstalled everything to the latest versions with rvm.  A lot of the stuff I'm googling says an older version of xcode, but when I run `xcodebuild -version` I get:

```
Xcode 4.5.2
Build version 4G2008a
```

Here's the full error on gem install rails:

```
jakes-MacBook-Pro:~ mctesterson$ sudo gem install rails
Fetching: i18n-0.6.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.4.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: activesupport-3.2.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: builder-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: activemodel-3.2.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.4.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-cache-1.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: journey-1.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: hike-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: tilt-1.3.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: sprockets-2.2.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: erubis-2.7.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-3.2.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: arel-3.0.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: tzinfo-0.3.35.gem (100%)
Fetching: activerecord-3.2.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: activeresource-3.2.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: mime-types-1.19.gem (100%)
Fetching: polyglot-0.3.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: treetop-1.4.12.gem (100%)
Fetching: mail-2.4.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionmailer-3.2.9.gem (100%)
Fetching: rake-10.0.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-ssl-1.3.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: thor-0.16.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: json-1.7.5.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/mctesterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling generator.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mctesterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mctesterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it was looking for my gcc stuff in the wrong place.

I ran the following and it worked:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2`

(looked at this article and found that under Franco's solution: [error: failed to build gem native extension when installing rails on mac mountian lion os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802918/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-installing-rails-on-mac-mountia))