# How do I upgrade Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby **and** Rails, as well as all this command line melarky. So please bear with me.

I have installed, RubyGems, Homebrew, RVM, Rails etc, by following various tutorials.

I think I have all of this going now, but when I type:

```
rails --version
```

I get, 3.2.12. I notice that Rails 4 is out. How do I upgrade to this version?

If I do:

```
gem install rails
```

Even doing:

```
gem update rails
```

I still get 3.2.12.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

When trying a few options here, I get this message returned...

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ ParanoidAndroid$ gem install rails --version=4.0
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:712:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

Seems there's an error happening. Any further ideas?

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using RVM then you should create a seperate gemset first like:

```
rvm gemset create whateverName
```

in this example I will install rails 4

```
rvm install 2.0.0

rvm list  

rvm 2.0.0
```

^^^^(you may need to copy and paste the version number exactly here as it was displayed in rvm list)

```
rvm gemset create rails4

rvm gemset use rails4
```

add the following to your gemfile for existing apps

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
```

then run

```
bundle update rails
```

or do following to just install the gem

```
gem install rails --version=4.0
```

### UPDATE

If you havne't installed Xcode 4.5 CLI tools then you will need to

Preferences > Downloads > Components

DMG

https://developer.apple.com/downloads

you may then also need to use homebrew to update gcc

brew install apple-gcc42

the following link has all the information you will need:

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried it and got an error. Could you see my update above?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802918/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-installing-rails-on-mac-mountia/13176057#13176057

Comment: When I get XCode open, there is no such CLI Tools in the components. I downloaded XCode 5.0.2. I m using Mac Mavericks.

Comment: seems the command line tools aren't offered after Xcode 5.0.1, maybe try... running the following command from the terminal: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: probably worth just trying brew install apple-gcc42 command as I should think that will fix the issue

Comment: Thanks! brew install apple-gcc42 did the trick. Seems XCode doesn't have CLTools after version 4.2

Answer (score 27):

If you already have a Rails project you should:

- Specify the desired version in your Gemfile (e.g. `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0.rc1'`)
- Run `bundle install` (`bundle update` may be needed)
- Run `rails app:update` (`rake rails:update` for 4.2 and earlier)
- Follow instructions on screen
- Follow [the official guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) for additional steps depending on your version

Comment: A great guide. It just worked for Rails 5.1 to 5.2 migration. Just one note that I have got ````require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup``` error so added `gem 'bootsnap'` to `Gemfile` to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

`gem update rails` does nothing for you, because `bundler` makes sure that only the gems specified in your `Gemfile` are loaded and used.

So in order to upgrade to Rails 4, you need to change the Rails version number in your Gemfile and run `bundle update rails`.

This Railscast guides you through all the steps of manually updating an existing application from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

Answer (score 3):

You can install either with specific version OR putting gem version in itself Gemfile.

```
gem install rails -v 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all gem versions with

```
gem list rails --remote --all
```

To install specify version 4.0.1 for example you can use

```
gem install rails -v 4.0.1
```

Or you could just specify the version in your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Best to use gem list --remote --all. Unless your looking for that particular version as long as the gemset for that project has been established