# Failed to build native gem extension - Rails Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I followed the instructions on the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802918/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-installing-rails-on-mac-mountia) but I still have the following error message:

```
Ayman$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
Ayman$ gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
--with-atomic_reference-dir
--without-atomic_reference-dir
--with-atomic_reference-include
--without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
--with-atomic_reference-lib
--without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The     compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in  `try_link0'
from /Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Ayman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Ayman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out

Ayman$
```

I am on the latest version of gems, running ruby 2.0.0, and Mac 10.8.

Any clue on what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

So I installed Xcode Command Line Tool per the following and am still recieving the following error message:

```
Ayman$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
--with-atomic_reference-dir
--without-atomic_reference-dir
--with-atomic_reference-include
--without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
--with-atomic_reference-lib
--without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The  compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:519:in     `try_link0'
from /Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:817:in `try_run'
from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-    p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Ayman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-  p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

Ayman$

**UPDATE TWO**

Followed rbenv install below per the following:

```
Ayman$ brew update
Updated Homebrew from 8e60080c to e7a77f80.
==> Updated Formulae
reposurgeon
Ayman$ brew install rbenv ruby-build
Warning: rbenv-0.4.0 already installed
Warning: ruby-build-20140110.1 already installed
Ayman$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
Ayman$ ~/.bash_profile
-bash: /Users/Ayman/.bash_profile: Permission denied
Ayman$ rbenv install 2.1.0
Downloading ruby-2.1.0.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/9e6386d53f5200a3e7069107405b93f7
Installing ruby-2.1.0...
Installed ruby-2.1.0 to /Users/Ayman/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0

Ayman$ rbenv rehash
Ayman$ rbenv global 2.1.0
Ayman$ gem install rails bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /Users/Ayman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic- 1.1.14/test/test_atomic.rb
```

Comment: Is Xcode command line tool installed?

Comment: Yes I have Xcode installed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353444/how-to-use-install-gcc-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-4 should help you.

Comment: Ok so I installed the Command Line Tool, restarted my computer, and went through the steps in the thread linked above and I'm still getting the same error. What gives?

Comment: You're not using `sudo` for your command, you really should as you won't have the necessary permissions otherwise.

Comment: Just tried running `sudo gem install rails` and I came back with the same error message

Comment: You probably need to symlink gcc? What does `which gcc` return?

Comment: Ayman$ which gcc
    /usr/bin/gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Turns out I was using an outdated version of gems.

Once I upgraded my gems to the latest version it worked fine.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try rvmsudo to use your rvm and have root privileges, maybe like this:

```
rvmsudo gem install rails
```

**EDIT**

I meant 'rvmsudo', not 'sudorvm'. Sorry for the mistake, I was on a phone.

Comment: `Ayman$ sudorvm gem install rails
-bash: sudorvm: command not found`

Comment: Just tried it with `rvmsudo` instead of `sudorvm` and that worked and prompted for a password and started initializing but then returning the same error message as before.

Comment: I just tried it again and now I get `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (http://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/minitest-4.7.5.gemspec.rz)`

Answer (score 1):

There is always [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x) where you can skip all the hassle of sudo and permissions.  Everything local to the user.  [Why rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F)?

```
brew update
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# if you dont have the init in your profile run the following:
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - --no-rehash)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# install a ruby
rbenv install 2.1.0
# you need to rehash after installing a ruby version or a global gem
rbenv rehash
# this will set 2.1.0 as your default ruby version in shell
rbenv global 2.1.0

# now try installing rails
gem install rails bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: I downloaded rbenv but can't seem to find the command to install rails. All docs tell me to simply run `gem install rails` and that brings back the same error message.

Comment: when I try `rbenv install rails` it tells me `ruby-build definition not found: rails` so I list available versions:

`Ayman$ rbenv install --list
Available versions:
  1.8.6-p383
  1.8.6-p420
  1.8.7-p249
  1.8.7-p302
  1.8.7-p334
  1.8.7-p352
  1.8.7-p357
  1.8.7-p358
  1.8.7-p370
  1.8.7-p371
  1.8.7-p374
  1.8.7-p375
  1.9.1-p378
  1.9.1-p430
  1.9.2-p0
  1.9.2-p180
  1.9.2-p290
  1.9.2-p318
  1.9.2-p320
  1.9.2-p326
  1.9.3-dev
  1.9.3-p0
  1.9.3-p125
  1.9.3-p194
  1.9.3-p286`

Comment: `  1.9.3-p327
  1.9.3-p362
  1.9.3-p374
  1.9.3-p385
  1.9.3-p392
  1.9.3-p429
  1.9.3-p448
  1.9.3-p484
  1.9.3-preview1
  1.9.3-rc1
  2.0.0-dev
  2.0.0-p0
  2.0.0-p195
  2.0.0-p247
  2.0.0-p353
  2.0.0-preview1
  2.0.0-preview2
  2.0.0-rc1
  2.0.0-rc2
  2.1.0
  2.1.0-dev
  2.1.0-preview1
  2.1.0-preview2
  2.1.0-rc1
  2.2.0-dev`

Comment: ` jruby-1.5.6
  jruby-1.6.3
  jruby-1.6.4
  jruby-1.6.5
  jruby-1.6.5.1
  jruby-1.6.6
  jruby-1.6.7
  jruby-1.6.7.2
  jruby-1.6.8
  jruby-1.7.0
  jruby-1.7.0-preview1
  jruby-1.7.0-preview2
  jruby-1.7.0-rc1
  jruby-1.7.0-rc2
  jruby-1.7.1
  jruby-1.7.10
  jruby-1.7.2
  jruby-1.7.3
  jruby-1.7.4
  jruby-1.7.5
  jruby-1.7.6
  jruby-1.7.7
  jruby-1.7.8
  jruby-1.7.9
  maglev-1.0.0
  maglev-1.1.0-dev
  maglev-2.0.0-dev
  mruby-dev
  rbx-1.2.4
  rbx-2.0.0
  rbx-2.0.0-dev
  rbx-2.0.0-rc1
  rbx-2.1.0
  rbx-2.1.1
  rbx-2.2.0
  rbx-2.2.1
  rbx-2.2.2
  rbx-2.2.3`

Comment: ree-1.8.6-2009.06
  ree-1.8.7-2009.09
  ree-1.8.7-2009.10
  ree-1.8.7-2010.01
  ree-1.8.7-2010.02
  ree-1.8.7-2011.03
  ree-1.8.7-2011.12
  ree-1.8.7-2012.01
  ree-1.8.7-2012.02
  topaz-dev

Comment: @aalab002 did you install a ruby yet with rbenv? You also need to do `brew install ruby-build` so you can build rubies.  Once you have that, try running `rbenv versions` if you dont see a ruby, try `rbenv install 2.1.0` then `rbenv rehash` then `rbenv global 2.1.0` followed by `gem install rails` and finally another `rbenv rehash`

Comment: @aalab002  I updated the original post with instructions

Comment: I updated the original question with my terminal log. The problem appears to be related to my permissions: `Ayman$ gem install rails bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/Ayman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/atomic-1.1.14/test/test_atomic.rb`

Comment: I tried `sudo gem install rails` again now the error message has changed to: `Ayman$ sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (http://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/minitest-4.7.5.gemspec.rz)`