# Trouble installing font-awesome gem, updating activesupport gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sass, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

I'm attempting to install the sass version of font-awesome into my foundation project. When I:

```
$ gem install font-awesome-sass
ERROR:  Error installing font-awesome-sass:
    railties requires activesupport (= 4.0.2)
```

When I attempt to update activesupport, from 3.2.12, I get this:

```
$ gem update activesupport
Updating installed gems
Updating activesupport
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing activesupport:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:410:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:495:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:784:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
Nothing to update
```

Not sure what dependencies I should be attempting to install, and don't want to load my project with anything that may be excess as it was working pretty flawlessly before. Thanks for any help :)

---

As was recommended, I tried $ gem install activesupport and this was returned:

```
$ gem install activesupport '4.0.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing activesupport:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/bin/ruby extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/bin/ruby
    --with-atomic_reference-dir
    --without-atomic_reference-dir
    --with-atomic_reference-include
    --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
    --with-atomic_reference-lib
    --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
/Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:410:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:495:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:784:in `try_run'
    from extconf.rb:26:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/davidpindrys/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '4.0.2' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Comment: try `gem install activesupport '4.0.2'` and then retry font-awesome

Comment: Here's the short of what that returned:

$ gem install activesupport '4.0.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing activesupport:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Do you use OSx?  If so check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802918/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-installing-rails-on-mac-mountia

Comment: I saw that post, but stopped when it suggested "installing rails", which I've done. Is there harm in installing it on top, again?

Comment: $ rails --version
Rails 3.2.12

Comment: I've never used rbenv before, but this line `The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.` looks like you need some general dev tools, it looks like xcode might have everything you need.  I'd consider installing that package as you need some general tools to compile stuff.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, rails is just a gem and you can install as many versions as you want.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm referring too, I just googled osx base development tools and that's what popped up.  I've never used a mac.

Comment: I think you may be on to something. I'm in xcode installing the "command line tools" package. Will update when it's done

Comment: Toolz- that did the trick. I installed the package from xcode, updated activesupport as you suggested, and was able to install the font-awesome-sass! Thank so much.